# Problems with the if else loop

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

Good morning everyone

My problem is very simple: I have numeric vector (example) and from this through if else loop
I would like to extract specific values.

```
example
 [1]  0.80  0.58  0.30  0.60  0.30  0.05  1.00  2.00 30.00  1.50
```

And this is my function which, however, always gives me the same mistake

```
    extractShips = function(i){
      ShippingCost = as.numeric()
       if(i <= 3){
        ShippingCost = 4.40
      }else if(i > 3 && i <= 5) {
        ShippingCost = 5.90
      }else if(i > 5 && i <= 10) {
        ShippingCost = 7.80
      }else if(i > 10 && i <= 25) {
        ShippingCost = 10.90
      }else if(i > 25 && i <= 50) {
        ShippingCost = 15.90
      }else if(i > 50 &&  i <= 100) {
        ShippingCost = 26.00
      }
    }

    **Error in if (y< 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed**


ships <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(example)) {ships <-c(ships, extractShips(example))
}
```

thanks in advance to anyone who wants to help me

```
Descrizione.gruppo Famiglia
1       2            3        0             0          80       ADJ  00BO "BORSE ZAINI CUSTODIE"     UA            "BORSE"      BNO
2      19           29        0             0         830       ADJ  00BO "BORSE ZAINI CUSTODIE"     UA            "BORSE"      BNO
3       0            0        0             0           1 CG MOBILE  00BO "BORSE ZAINI CUSTODIE"     UA            "BORSE"      BNO
4       0            1        0             0           1    KOOPER  00BO "BORSE ZAINI CUSTODIE"     UA            "BORSE"      MY1
5       0            1        0             0           3    LENOVO  00BO "BORSE ZAINI CUSTODIE"     UA            "BORSE"      BNO
6       0            0        0             0           1  RIVACASE  00BO "BORSE ZAINI CUSTODIE"     UA            "BORSE"      BNO
  Descrizione.famiglia    Peso  Volume             EAN End.user
1     "BORSA NOTEBOOK"   "0.8" "0.004" "8054608902756"    17.89
2     "BORSA NOTEBOOK" "0.575"  "0.01" "8054608903197"     8.01
3     "BORSA NOTEBOOK"   "0.3" "0.004" "3700740423042"    40.25
4 "SPORT/TEMPO LIBERO"   "0.6"  "0.01" "8029121921928"    30.99
5     "BORSA NOTEBOOK"   "0.3" "0.001" "0193638156338"    43.57
6     "BORSA NOTEBOOK" "0.575" "0.009" "4260403573389"     18.2
>
```

Comment: If `example` is a vector, it would nave `NULL` rows. You might want to look at `cut()` or `switch()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `apply` family function instead of a for loop.

```
#First get rid of NA's in the data:
focelda_grezzo$Peso[is.na(focelda_grezzo$Peso)] <- 0

# Define function:
extractShips = function(i){
  ShippingCost = as.numeric()
  if(i <= 3){
    ShippingCost = 4.40
  }else if(i > 3 && i <= 5) {
    ShippingCost = 5.90
  }else if(i > 5 && i <= 10) {
    ShippingCost = 7.80
  }else if(i > 10 && i <= 25) {
    ShippingCost = 10.90
  }else if(i > 25 && i <= 50) {
    ShippingCost = 15.90
  }else if(i > 50 &&  i <= 100) {
    ShippingCost = 26.00
  }
}

# Create a new column using your function
focelda_grezzo$ShippingCost <- sapply(focelda_grezzo$Peso, extractShips)
```

Comment: To specify; is the column of a dataframe. I also tried with map_df () but nothing. At most it goes up to line number 100 and then only writes 0

Comment: I can't understand your comment - is it missing some words? What is a column of a dataframe? You say that `example` is a vector?

Comment: I'm sorry. Example is the column of a dataframe that contains the weight of some products. With this function I would like to get the shipping cost based on weight

Comment: I tried with a trivial function but I get the same error. The error is in the function.                     function (i){
  if(i > 0){
    print("ok")
  }else if(i < 1) {
    print("NO")
  }
}

Comment: I've tried to work out your data based on your comments and edited my answer.  I'm not sure what you mean regarding a trivial function. If this still doesn't work, I think you need to provide an example of your data.

Comment: I'm sorry but always the same mistake. The elements of the column are all numeric and I don't understand why the function is wrong. I did the test with both apply and sapply

Comment: Edit your question to show outputs of `head(dataframe)` and `str(dataframe)` where `dataframe` is the name of your table containing the weights. Otherwise it's impossible to help.

Comment: I don't think it changes much. The "Peso" column is the one that interests me. From this column I would like to get the shipping costs so for me the error remains in the function I wrote (extractShips). 
I've added the dataframe I'm working on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242774/discussion-between-stefano-maria-de-francesco-and-rw2).

Comment: I had some NA that I hadn't seen. Thanks for the reply @rw2